# how to equate key.chars with its name

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I created a Text widget from Tkinter and when a user types something I want to collect it is as a word for example if the user press backspace the last letter should be removed or if it other letters, it should be printed. However, when I try to equalize keys. chars with its own name I return nothing

```
self.text.bind('<Key>', self.callback)


def callback(self, event):
    key = '{k!r}'.format(k=event.char)
    if key == '\x08' : # backspace
        self.keys = self.keys[:-1]
```

Comment: `event.char` is only meaningful when a printable key was pressed.  For cursor control keys like backspace, you need to check `event.keysym` instead - I think it will be "BackSpace" in this case.

Comment: it didnt work even if i use alphabetical letters. for example, I used "w' instead of "\x08" but still it doesn't work

Comment: Oh, you're setting `key` to the `repr()` of `event.char`, for some reason.  That puts quotes in the string, so you'd have to have quotes in the string you're comparing it to for there to be a match.  You should probably be using the `event` fields directly, rather than applying any formatting to them.

Comment: thank you for your response.